# How to delete only one element in an array from the local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
var details = [{
    "Name": "Bhavani",
        "Phone No": ["123456", "123456"],
        "Email Id": ["mamata@gmail.com", "mamata@yahoo.com"],
        "Birthday": "21/16/22/33"
}, {
    "Name": "Mamata",
        "Phone No": ["123456", "123456"],
        "Email Id": ["mamata@gmail.com", "mamata@yahoo.com"],
        "Birthday": "21/16/22/33"
}];

function add() {
    localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(details));
    str = localStorage.getItem("contacts");
}

function removeItems(){
  var s = localStorage.removeItem("contacts");
  alert(s);
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/vjnsd5wo/3/).

How can I delete only one element from an array and not the whole local storage?

Comment: Given that you are storing a JSON string, you need to read it, parse it, modify, serialise again, then store it back. No shortcuts.

Comment: If i want to delete one element in that object how can we do it...i mean name ,phone number etc..of only one person must be deleted...If iam writing var s=localStorage.removeItem("contacts"); the whole content of local storage is deleted

Comment: localstorage is just like an object. use what you use to delete a property from an object: `delete localStorage["contacts"]`

Comment: Yes  but if i make that array of object as an contact list...I cant delete whole contacts right..i need to delete only the specifies person details....thats my question

Comment: @NagaBhavani then get that string back, parse it using `JSON.parse`, remove it from array using `splice` and then stringify it and store it against 'contacts'

Comment: yes i got it..thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The code example for my comment under the question - removing Email Id from Mamata:

```
var details = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
details.filter(function(e) {
  return e.Name === "Mamata"
}).forEach(function(element) {
  delete element["Email Id"];
});
localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(details));
```

**EDIT**: If you want to remove a whole record and not a field in it, this should do it:

```
var details = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
details = details.filter(function(e) {
  return e.Name !== "Mamata"
});
localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(details));
```

Comment: sorry for interruption,...can u plz say how to delete 

"Name": "Bhavani",
        "Phone No": ["123456", "123456"],
        "Email Id": ["mamata@gmail.com", "mamata@yahoo.com"],
        "Birthday": "21/16/22/33"

from details array object from local storage

Answer (score -2):

```
localStorage.setItem("contacts",localStorage.getItem("contacts").split(',').splice(...));
```

Comment: Splitting and splicing JSON is a bad idea that is sure to backfire; and it's not a working solution (the interesting bit is pixellated with `...`).